# My site is running so slow, please take a look and see if i made a simple mistake

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, pagespeed

So my website http://www.uniconutrition.com is running too slow. My home page is php because i need to show latest blog post from the wordpress hosted blog. All the other html pages on the site load up nice and quick but the homepage just takes so long. I'm not the most experienced developer so it might be some quick fix that I'm missing- please let me know what you see and thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Show us the source code for the home page for starters.

Comment: What host do you use? Wordpress alone would have to be totally out of whack to cripple performance. If you customized the site with horrendous manual sql queries that contained nested joins and in selects and such maybe, but if you're not the most experienced developer, I doubt you went that far.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.uniconutrition.com_2F&mobile=false

Answer (score 3):

Your site is relatively heavy (1.03 MB). Make sure all of your Javascript is [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)), all of your images are [compressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression), and that you're only loading things you absolutely need for the website.

Another thing you may want to try is putting your images into a [spritesheet](http://www.codeandweb.com/what-is-a-sprite-sheet) and selectively loading them from it. Using a spritesheet would load many of the images in one request, thus cutting down the time waiting for a response from the server.

From a quick look in the Network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools, these appear to be taking the longest to load:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After quickly looking over your source code the first thing I noticed is you have 6 link tags for your CSS.  Try and combine those and make sure they're minified.  The more http requests your page has the less efficient it is.

The next thing I noticed is the size of some of your images are HUGE.  What ever athenahero_03.png is, is 600KB alone.  You need to optimize your images.

If you're using Firefox, install the Firebug extension and use the Net panel to see all of the resources your site is downloading and their sizes.